# Emulate search and get row number of returned row (from total)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logic

I'm a begginer in MySQL and have been searching for a solution for this problem for a few hours now. I found a few answers, but can't seem to implement them.

Basically, heres what I want to do:

I want to find how a user from from a given country would rank compared to other users from the same country when they are ranked by ID

For example: 
Joe is ID 10 and is from the US 
There are 100 users from the US 
Result: Joe ranks 10th

How would I convert this to an MySQL query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show table with some data

Comment: is the ID and the rank same?

Comment: In my table I only have 2 columns - **id** and **country**

Comment: @affaz Yes, I would like to get the rank for a given user based on his ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 user variables,eg,`running` & `previous` which gets the previous rank number and accordingly calculate the rank number of the `country` by incrementing the current value by 1.

```
select u.id,u.country,u.rank 
from (
    select u1.id,u1.country,
        @running:=if(@previous=concat(u1.id,u1.country),@running,0) + 1 as rank,
        @previous:=concat(u1.id,u1.country) 
    from tablename u1
    order by concat(t.id,t.country) 
) u;
```

Replace `tablename` with your table